# Can I open my singleplayer world to multiplayer without exiting?

Tags: terraria

Every now and then, I am playing Terraria and a friend on Steam asks if they can join. I then have to exit the world and re-open it as a server in order for them to be able to join.

So, is there a way I can **open my world to Steam multiplayer** (i.e. the equivalent of the 'Host & Play' option on the multiplayer menu) **without exiting the world and re-joining?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, as far as I can recall that is not possible.
What I like to do though, is just launching with Host & Play right away and setting a password for the server. This way my friends can join whenever they want but I can also keep everyone out who is not supposed to play with me.

Comment: This isn't exactly the best option for me, as I often pause my game by minimising the window, which you can't do in Multiplayer. When it is opened to multiplayer I can be assured that my friend will be there to protect me.

Comment: Ah alright, well best option on that is building a box around you, works well if you are not in the corruption or anywhere else where worms spawn.

Comment: I usually pause this way when I have to answer the phone etc, so building a box is a little bit too slow. But anyway, thanks for answering, if I have no new answers by the end of the day I will accept.